# VB.Net How to Use Remove Flicker and Disable ALT F4 Together

Tags: vb.net

I have code here that disables the flicker. I add this to the designer:

```
'Remove Flicker Lag
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000
            ' Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property
```

I also have this code that prevents the form to be alt + f4 and I add this in the code of the form that I want to prevent from being alt f4

```
  Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            Const CS_NOCLOSE As Integer = &H200
            cp.ClassStyle = cp.ClassStyle Or CS_NOCLOSE
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property
```

But I cant use them together. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why can't you use them together? What happens when you just set both  `ClassStyle` and `ExStyle` in the same `Get`?

Comment: @AConfusedSimpleton - Thanks Now its working ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I added them together. Thanks @AConfusedSimpleton.

```
 Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Const CS_NOCLOSE As Integer = &H200
            Const WS_EX_COMPOSITED As Integer = &H2000000

            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams

            ' Enable compositing to reduce flicker
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or WS_EX_COMPOSITED

            ' Disable close button and Alt+F4
            cp.ClassStyle = cp.ClassStyle Or CS_NOCLOSE

            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property
```